# Azure Database Overnight Copy

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have 2 databases hosted in Azure, a production and a staging environment. Overnight, I want the staging database to be cleared and restored with a copy of the production database.

Does anyone know if this is possible through azure or would i need to write my own custom script? I looked at Azure Data Sync but that looks like it would merge the data.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

first take a [database backup of production to a storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export-powershell)

```
$subscriptionId = "YOUR AZURE SUBSCRIPTION ID"

Login-AzureRmAccount
Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

# Database to export
$DatabaseName = "DATABASE-NAME"
$ResourceGroupName = "RESOURCE-GROUP-NAME"
$ServerName = "SERVER-NAME"
$serverAdmin = "ADMIN-NAME"
$serverPassword = "ADMIN-PASSWORD" 
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $serverPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $serverAdmin, $securePassword

# Generate a unique filename for the BACPAC
$bacpacFilename = $DatabaseName + (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm") + ".bacpac"

# Storage account info for the BACPAC
$BaseStorageUri = "https://STORAGE-NAME.blob.core.windows.net/BLOB-CONTAINER-NAME/"
$BacpacUri = $BaseStorageUri + $bacpacFilename
$StorageKeytype = "StorageAccessKey"
$StorageKey = "YOUR STORAGE KEY"

$exportRequest = New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $ServerName `
   -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -StorageKeytype $StorageKeytype -StorageKey $StorageKey -StorageUri $BacpacUri `
   -AdministratorLogin $creds.UserName -AdministratorLoginPassword $creds.Password
$exportRequest

# Check status of the export
Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $exportRequest.OperationStatusLink
```

Now [try restoring using below powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/restore-azurermsqldatabase)

```
# Restore a database to a previous point in time

#$resourceGroupName = {resource-group-name}
#$serverName = {server-name}
$newRestoredDatabaseName = "{new-database-name}"
$localTimeToRestoreTo = "{12/9/2016 12:00:00 PM}" # change to a valid restore point for your database
$restorePointInTime = (Get-Date $localTimeToRestoreTo).ToUniversalTime()
$newDatabaseEdition = "Basic"
$newDatabaseServiceLevel = "Basic"

Write-Host "Restoring database '$databaseName' to its state at:"(Get-Date $restorePointInTime).ToLocalTime()", to a new database named '$newRestoredDatabaseName'."

$restoredDb = Restore-AzureRmSqlDatabase -FromPointInTimeBackup -PointInTime $restorePointInTime -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
 -ServerName $serverName -TargetDatabaseName $newRestoredDatabaseName -Edition $newDatabaseEdition -ServiceObjectiveName $newDatabaseServiceLevel `
 -ResourceId $databaseToRestore.ResourceID

$restoredDb
```

these [entire things can be automated as well](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-intro)

Comment: Thank you for this! I added it as an automation runbook in azure and working like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Copy database" feature to copy either to the same or another logical server:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-copy